# What's the difference between v-model.trim and v-model?

Tags: vue.js, calendar, v-model

[image]
It's occurring error  when I am using **v-model.trim** with Calendar

```
<Calendar id="birth_date" v-model.trim="employeeSetup.birth_date" :showButtonBar="true" required="true" :class="{'p-invalid': submitted && !employeeSetup.birth_date}" ref="birth_date" v-on:keyup.enter="this.$refs.gender.$el.focus()" />
```

But it's working perfectly when I am using **v-model.trim** with InputText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim` is a modifier that removes any extra space in your input text :

```
<input type="text" v-model.trim="name" />
```

it uses the js function `trim()` of strings :

```js
let s="brahim "
console.log(s+'boussadjra')
let t=s.trim() //removes the space

console.log(t+'boussadjra')
```

the calendar is a custom component which is not a simple input

Comment: Here is a link to the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#trim